# LibGDX Ashley Separate Render and Update

Tags: java, libgdx, entity

I just switched over to using Ashley for handling Entity Systems, however I can't seem to figure out the best way to separate updating the game logic and rendering. I have a system called `RenderSystem` which simply loops through all entities that have a `RenderComponent`, `PositionComponent`, and a `TextureComponent` and then draw them to the screen. However, as of right now, I have the engine updating in my update loop which only updates at a maximum 60 times per second. I would like to update physics, input, and other game logic in this update loop, while doing all of the rendering separately in another loop that isn't capped.

What's the best practice for separating render systems and update systems in Ashley?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can exploit Java's multi-threading features and create multiple Ashley engine instances (that share a common entity pool) and have them run in separate threads. Not sure how you'd go about syncing data between the two engines but if you can pull it off then you'll have engines that can loop over their entities using independent frame rates.